# Why session.getAttribute() always returning null inside JSP page textbox?

Tags: sql, jsp, servlets

I am always getting **null** value in jsp page textbox. I have defined name attribute in index.jsp page and fetching value using `<%=session.getAttribute()%>`.

**Here is index.jsp**

```html
<tr>
<td>First Name</td>
<td>
<input type="text" required="" name="firstname" value="<%=session.getAttribute("firstname")%>"/>
</td>
</tr>
```

**In below UploadServletClass.java, session is defined**

```html
public class UploadServletClass extends HttpServlet{
 PrintWriter out = null;
 Connection con = null;
 PreparedStatement ps = null;
 HttpSession session = null;
    
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException{
   response.setContentType("text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
     try{
       out = response.getWriter();
       session = request.getSession();
       ...
       }
    }
}
```

**This is loginScript.jsp**

```html
<%
String zfid = request.getParameter("zid");    
String fname = request.getParameter("firstname");

...

if (rs.next()) {
session.setAttribute("zfid", zfid); //used ${sessionScope.zfid} to display value into textbox and it is successful.
session.setAttribute("firstname",fname); //failed to display value in textbox 
//out.println("welcome " + userid);
//out.println("<a href='logout.jsp'>Log out</a>");
response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
}
```

Comment: I tried many solutions from stackoverflow. Didn't found any solution.

Comment: Does `fname` has any value or not? Check and see onces .

Comment: Hi @Swati. I wrote String fname = request.getParameter("firstname");
 out.println(fname); and it print null on screen

Comment: @Swati Could you please help me to solve this issue. It would be really helpful for me.

Comment: from where are you taking this input ?

Comment: I am taking input(firstname) from index.jsp page and in index.jsp page  I am writing name = firstname and value="<%=session.getAttribute("firstname")%>".

Comment: I am still trying

Comment: and where are you setting this value ? `<%=session.getAttribute("firstname")%>"` ?

Comment: I am setting '<%=session.getAttribute("firstname")%>' in index.jsp page.

Comment: what about `loginScript,jsp` you have get the value `fname` there and then set value there only . Debug your code ,check if in `loginScript.jsp` the value is coming or not .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210588/discussion-between-priya-dhanba-and-swati).

Comment: I did code for "firstname" same as like "zfid"

Comment: actually I am trying to fetch row value from sql table into JSP textbox. When I tried to fetch "zfid" from then it is fetched. But why I am not able to fetch "firstname" in same way.